# Passing a variable to init function (variable scope issue)

Tags: jquery, variables, scope, stellar.js

I'm using stellar.js for a parallax image effect.  I'm trying to pass a variable to the stellar.js init function but it's not working.  The plugin is initialized in my $(document).ready() function (NOT a requirement) where I also do a bit of math because I can't hardcode the numbers when I initialize stellar.js.  Here's the code in question.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
   var $height = $("img").height(); // i.e. $height = 1000px
   var $offset = $height * .75;     // i.e. $offset = 750px;

    $(window).stellar({
      horizontalScrolling: false,
      verticalOffset: $offset
    });

 )};
```

If I just put in 750 as the verticalOffset in the stellar init function it works fine. However, using the $offset variable does not work as it seems to be out of scope of the $(window).stellar() function. Can anyone help me out with this?  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to put a break point into a stellar.js file code to see what options are passed there during initialization (actually, I got the same value I'd passed)? If you think, the problem with a scope, maybe you should try something like that:

```js
$(window).stellar({
      horizontalScrolling: false,
      verticalOffset: $("img").height() * .75
    });
```

By the way, there is a misprint in your code, as it should be **});** instead of **)};** at the end

Comment: I never even thought of that, but it works! Thank you very much! I've been coding and staring at this for hours and needed a fresh set of eyes.